# Create new signal or multiplex SIGALRM?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, signals

I am trying to write a benchmark that receives a signal from the kernel telling it to adjust its parameters. I'm trying to study whether a proactive or reactive approach works best.

In the proactive approach, I use `setitimer` to set an alarm periodically and force the benchmark to look at its performance thus far and re-tune itself.

In the reactive approach, the kernel periodically monitors the process and signals it if it is performing poorly.

Since I've been using the `setitimer` functionality, and since `setitimer` causes `SIGALRM`, I have asked the kernel to throw a `SIGALRM` in the reactive approach. This has been working fine. However, now I need to use `SIGALRM` to run the benchmark for a specific duration of time.

Is there a way to multiplex `SIGALRM` to serve both purposes - to do a timed run and terminate **and** to re-tune. Is there a function/syscall similar to `setitimer` that allows the user to set an alarm but with a custom signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You want to look at the [timer_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) / [timer_settime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html) etc., family of calls.

The 2nd parameter of `timer_create` is a `struct sigevent`.  The field within that, `sigev_signo` can be set to send a specific signal number on timer expiration.